# Who actually nuked the Karakum?

Tags: plot-device, the-expanse-2015

Warning: Contains spoilers to "The Expanse" Season 2.

In "The Expanse" Season 2, the Martian Ship "Karakum" apparently carries out some black ops mission on Ganymede. It gets destroyed while at or above it's landing site.

[image: Karakum target identified]

Here's what I know, but not quite understand:

- In the [Pjotr/Errinwright scene where Pjotr dies](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheExpanse/comments/65569f/show_piotr_the_way_to_the_next_whiskey_bar/), his terminal shows a target identification on the "Karakum". See screenshot.
- Later in the movie, Errinwright claims to Mr. Mao he has given the order to destroy the ship, but I think this is just a bluff (based on the previous scene probably)

What should the message in the screenshot infer? Who did destroy the ship? Should that be even clear from the movie?

Comment: I assumed that "target identified: MCRN Karakum" means that Karakum was identified as target of the attack - and that some limits are not allowing to communicate more.

Comment: " It gets destroyed while at or above it's landing site." - above. It is mentioned that it is disappeared from radar and replaced by expanding field of debris. Field of debris (remain of Karakum) is showed to be in space above Ganymede.